# How to lower the brightness of the screen?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios6

How can I change the brightness of the screen on button click? I am using this code

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.3f];
```

but it's not working any more. I have put this code in a button click action. Is there any special thing I need to do with this or any framework I need to include?

Answer (score 0):

in my application i used this :

```
//take slider in .h file

  self.slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(give your frame)];

self.slider.minimumValue = 0;//here you have to set min value of slider as per you want
self.slider.maximumValue = 1;//here you have to set max value of slider as per you want
 self.slider.continuous = YES;

int myVal = self.slider.value;
NSString *timeValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%1d", myVal];

self.timeLabel.text = timeValue;

 // Attach an action to sliding
  [self.slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

 - (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{
  [self adjustImageBrightnessWithValue:sender.value];
}

- (void)adjustImageBrightnessWithValue:(CGFloat)value
{
  [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:value];
}
```

may it will helpful to you,thanks.

Comment: Thanx dev. But I don't think there is any difference bet your method - (void)adjustImageBrightnessWithValue:(CGFloat)value
{
  [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:value];
}                                                                 and that one I mention.                                      [[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.3f]; is so?